# How to get cell color in google sheet using gspread python

Tags: python, google-sheets, cell, gspread, gspread-formatting

I wanted to fetch cell color using gspread and apply this color to another cell but I am unable to find a way to extract cell color using gspread-formatting

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks for responding but there's no code. I wanted to fetch cell color of google sheet and apply it to another cell. So can I perform this using gspread_formatting library. If yes how? Any sample code?